# Cannot login without password even with SSH key

Tags: ssh

I have 2 shell accounts ont 2 different hosts:

- shell A: shell I want to login using a SSH key (server-A.com)
- shell B: shell I'm using to login to A without a password but using SSH key (server-B.com)

I emailed the server-A.com sysadmin who gave me the bellow tutorial URLs.

I've done the following:

- Created a private/public SSH key on server-A.com using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C username@server-A.com` and put the private key on server-B.com
  in `~/.ssh/server-B.com`
- I ran `chmod 700 ~/.ssh/` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/server-B.com`
- I added server-A.com public key to to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server-B.com

  ```
  $ cat ~/.ssh/server-B.com.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys     # on server-B.com
  ```
- I've checked `~/.ssh/config` (no) and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which contained the following (other # comment lines not printed)

  ```
  #   PasswordAuthentication yes
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
  HashKnownHosts yes
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
  ```

  From shell B:

  ```
  $ ssh-keygen -f "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts" -R server-A.com
  ```

**NOTE:** I followed the tutorials on https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews and https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-openssh/.

What went wrong?

Comment: Running your `ssh` commands with the `-vvv` option will provide a lot of debugging information that can narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the private key on `B` to log into `A`. Don't generate the key on the remote `A` system.  A remote system does not need to know your private identity.

You are wanting to log into the `A` system from `B`.  This means that the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` *on the `A` system* should contain the public key (to allow you to enter). The `B` system does not need this file locally for you to log into `A`.

Note that you will have to make sure that the `~/.ssh` on both hosts has `700` permissions and that the files within has `600` permissions (including `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `A`).

Also, to actually *use* the key in the file `~/.ssh/server-B.com` on `B` to log into `A`, you would have to use `ssh` as

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/server-B.com  a-user@server-A.com
```

Alternatively, start an `ssh-agent` and add the key to it:

```
eval "$( ssh-agent )"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/server-B.com

ssh a-user@A-system.com
```

And/or, add an entry in `~/.ssh/config` on `B` for the `A` system like

```
Host A
    User a-user
    Hostname server-A.com
    IdentityFile %d/.ssh/server-B.com
```

and then use

```
ssh A
```

You could also just use the *default* name of the key file, unless you have other private keys already.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a publickey authentication option on the host in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Uncomment and set to yes

Ensure you are editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the host, not /etc/ssh/ssh_config. The second files is for clients only

If needed, contact the admin of host A

Comment: The fact that the admin on `A` gives them a tutorial should be evidence enough that public key authentication is a valid method already.

Comment: @Kusalananda from what I saw, they were editing the wrong file. Although it may be valid, unless there is a typo, they will never get it enabled. They said they are editing ssh_config, not sshd_config

Comment: The user clearly does not have access to the `sshd_config` on the `A` host. In any case neither `ssh_config` nor `sshd_config` should need any edits on either system.

Comment: @Kusalananda well, in that case, there is probably no way to get keys up and running. If the entry is wrong (which to me looks like it is) there is no way to fix it without contacting the server admin

Comment: checking ~/.ssh/authorized_keys I realised that it was ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.temp as I renamed
to keep a backup while doing other operations and forgot to rename it back.

this is my mistake, sorry for that and tank's for your help

Comment: @user2901196 you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't get everything wrong, only part.

To use client authentication by publickey (crypto) in SSH:

- you must have the privatekey file on the *client* -- your B.

  Best practice is to *generate* the key on the client. What you did, 
  generate on the server and copy, is not recommended, but will work.

  Best practice is to use the standard filenames (depending on 'type' aka algorithm) on the client -- `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for RSA (in v2), `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` for ECDSA, etc. `ssh-keygen` would do this by default if run on the client. Using a different name like you did means that you must specify the filename every time you run `ssh`, like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/server-B.com user@host [command...]`, or else set up your config file to specify this as your `IdentityFile` (either globally or for the particular host).

  The privatekey file must be inaccessible by other users. AFAICS your `chmod`'s got that right.
- you put the publickey in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ON THE *SERVER* -- your A.

  Using `cat >>` is generally good, as it retains any existing content and appends the new line. If there are existing lines that (you are certain) are obsolete -- for keys, or users, that are no longer in use or authorized -- you may want to delete them to keep things tidy, but it isn't necessary.

  And the `authorized_keys` file must be unwritable by other users. This may or may not be the default on your system; if not, use `chmod` in the same way as you did for the keyfile.
- removing the entry for the server (A) from the `known_hosts` file on client (B) is needed only when the *server* key is changed, or obsoleted. It is unrelated to client authentication. Doing so unnecessarily, if you aren't careful to manually check the server key fingerprint when next asked, may provide an opening for an attacker to intercept, steal, and alter your data.

So, if you fix `authorized_keys` on the server (A) and run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/server-B.com user@serveraname` on the client (B), and if asked verify the server fingerprint, it should work. If it doesn't, run with several `-v` options as commented by Haxiel to get details. In particular if it doesn't seem to see the specified keyfile (aka identityfile), recheck the permissions with `ls -l`.